# Is there any way to build a scraper that fetches contact info from different websites with different structures using python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I need to build a scraper that fetches contact info from different websites with different structures using python. I have tried doing it but since websites have different structures code doesn't for all.

Is this doable or should I need to write code for each website idiviadually?

Comment: You need to change your code everytime the pattern you follow changes

Comment: This is a broad question, do you have examples? I guess you could use regex for common patterns. Otherwise, you have to make a parser ad-hoc for each website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way of getting information from different websites, due to different architectures on how the websites are built. It is very rare that different websites have the same class values and IDs used.